# remove sites restriction

Tags: windows

I had restrict on some web site from server and I want any way to remove this restrict on sites .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to get round a company policy could land you in trouble at best or even get you dismissed at worst.

If you need access to certain sites for legitimate work reasons talk to your manager and make the case. If they agree then they should talk to IT to get those sites unblocked.

Using proxies or random software you downloaded from the internet isn't the way to do it.